# Can't install System.Data.OleDb

Tags: visual-studio-2017, installation, oledb

I tried install System.Data.OleDb to my project, but got this error message : 
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/cd8b36741a610a4d7d490ece6a892831599377ab.png

Not sure what to do, and what could solve this problem.

Comment: The issue is quite simple. The reason is that your project's target framework version is v3.5 and too old and `System.Data.OleDb` is published after `v3.5`. So  the nuget package does not support net framework 3.5. The way is to change your project framework version to `>=4.6.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't install System.Data.OleDb

The main reason is that [System.Data.OleDb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.OleDb/5.0.0-preview.3.20214.6) does not support framework version < `v4.6.1`. See this:

[image]

Besides,from your error message, your project is target to use `Net Framework 3.5`. So the error occurs.

**Solution**

To solve the issue, you should right-click on your project-->`Properties`-->`Application`-->change **Target Framework** to  **>=** `Net Framework 4.6.1`.

Hope it could help you.